# output file new line not start from the nextline

Tags: java, junit, output, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I am having trouble with the space.
How can I print out the output file correctly?
When I run my code, which is like.....

This is how my main method looks like, and generate the output file.....

```
main()....{
File stats = new File(statFile);
    stats.createNewFile();

// my code here.... the stat values change here.



    FileWriter statFileWriter = new FileWriter(stats, true);
    BufferedWriter statsOutput = new BufferedWriter(statFileWriter);
    statsOutput.write(Stats.printStat());
    statsOutput.flush();
}
```

This is the Stat class that I can change the values in the program, and print out the string with the values.

```
public class Stats {
public static String dataFile = "";
public static int cacheHits = 0;
public static int diskReads = 0;    
public static int diskWrites = 0;
public static long executionTime = 0;

public static String printStat() {
    String print = "";

    print += "Sort on " + dataFile;
    print += "\nCache Hits: " + cacheHits;
    print += "\nDisk Reads: " + diskReads;
    print += "\nDisk Writes: " + diskWrites;
    print += "\nTime is " + executionTime;
    return print;
}
}
```

This should make output like:

```
Sort on sorted_b.dat
Cache Hits: 30922
Disk Reads: 1
Disk Writes: 1
Time is 16
Sort on sorted_a.dat
Cache Hits: 62899
Disk Reads: 2
Disk Writes: 2
Time is 0
```

But When I run the main twice in the testcase, the actual output was:

```
Sort on sorted_b.dat
Cache Hits: 30922
Disk Reads: 1
Disk Writes: 1
Time is 16Sort on sorted_a.dat    ------> the new stat is not start from the nextline.
Cache Hits: 62899
Disk Reads: 2
Disk Writes: 2
Time is 0
```

if I add extra "/n" at the end of the 
    print += "\nTime is " + executionTime; this line, like
print += "\nTime is " + executionTime + \n;

It will make extra one more line at the end, like

```
Sort on sorted_b.dat
Cache Hits: 30922
Disk Reads: 1
Disk Writes: 1
Time is 16
Sort on sorted_a.dat
Cache Hits: 62899
Disk Reads: 2
Disk Writes: 2
Time is 0
          ------------blank, but extra line.
```

How can I print the output with no extra line, and correct printed?

Comment: Though you haven't posted it, presumably you have some code that is outputting `printStat()` multiple times into the same file. Output a newline between successive calls to `printStat()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your main method into:

```
File stats = new File(statFile);
Boolean fromStart = stats.createNewFile();

// my code here.... the stat values change here.  

FileWriter statFileWriter = new FileWriter(stats, true);
BufferedWriter statsOutput = new BufferedWriter(statFileWriter);
if(fromStart == false) statsOutput.write("\n");
statsOutput.write(Stats.printStat());
statsOutput.flush();
```

`Boolean fromStart` that returned from `stats.createNewFile()` will be:

- `true` if the file is created for the first time --> no need to add additional newline.
- `false` if the file already exists --> need to add a newline before writing new contents.

Comment: edited to correct the placement of newline print (doh)

Answer (score 0):

you need to append additional "\n" at end

```
public class Stats 
{
public static String dataFile = "";
public static int cacheHits = 0;
public static int diskReads = 0;    
public static int diskWrites = 0;
public static long executionTime = 0;

    public static String printStat() 
    {
        String print = "";

        print += "Sort on " + dataFile;
        print += "\nCache Hits: " + cacheHits;
        print += "\nDisk Reads: " + diskReads;
        print += "\nDisk Writes: " + diskWrites;
        print += "\nTime is " + executionTime+"\n";
        return print;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main method, just use `BufferedWriter`'s [`newLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine%28%29) method, like that:

```
FileWriter statFileWriter = new FileWriter(stats, true);
BufferedWriter statsOutput = new BufferedWriter(statFileWriter);
statsOutput.write(Stats.printStat());
statsOutput.newLine();
```

You can also add a new line before writing stats, if you wish.